# Show that $R/I$ is a field, where $R$ is a PID , where $I$ is a nonzero prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I \neq \{0\} $ be a proper ideal of a $PID$ $R$ such that the quotient ring $R/I$ has no zero divisors.

I have a problem in showing that $R/I$ is a field.
Help Needed!!

Comment: So what do you know about PID? $R/I$ being a integral domain means $I$ is a non zero prime ideal. Doe this help?

Answer (score 5):

Are you familiar with prime and maximal ideals?  The assumption is that $I$ is prime.  $R/I$ is a field iff $I$ is maximal.  So you'd like to show that nonzero prime ideals in a PID are maximal.  Can you do that?

Comment: but here it is not given that R is commutative

Comment: Normally a PID is assumed commutative.

Comment: @Loper if $R$ is not commutative then the quotient need not be a field. A PID is generally defined to be commutative.

Answer (score 2):

First prove that $I$ is prime:

let $ab\in I$ for $a,b\in R$ then. $ab+I=I\implies (a+I)(b+I)=I \implies a+I\in I\ or\ b+I\in I$
since $R/I$ has no zero divisors

Thus $I$ is prime and in a PID every non zero prime ideal is maximal

Answer (score 1):

$I$ is generated by a single element $p$. The fact that $R/I$ has no zero divisors mean that if $ab\in R$ is divisible by $p$, then either $a$ is divisible by $p$ or $b$ is. Thus $p$ is prime. The maximal nonzero ideals in a PID are exactly the ideals generated by a single prime element. Thus $I$ is a maximal ideal, hence $R/I$ is a field.